# How to test smpt with automated telnet from bash script?

Tags: bash, smtp, telnet, mail-server

I want to make a bash script that calls automatically smtp port 25 and sends email then I assert that email is queued

I have this much code now
https://github.com/kristijorgji/docker-mailserver/blob/main/tests/smpt.bash

but is not working, I get always

```
 improper command pipelining after DATA from unknown[172.21.0.1]: subject: Test 2022-07-22_17_10_09\r\nA nice test\r\n\r\n
```

That might be also ok, but please double check my script and give suggestions for improvements if it is ok or fixes

How can I automate this process so I can re-run the script after every configuration change ?
I want to know the best practices

Comment: `telnet` actually sends some extra garbage-- use `ncat` instead

Comment: i am researching it. Any example ? If you have something working feel free also to make pr ;) my repository is public and open source for all or coment here. Never used ncat befor

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The `PIPELINING` extension to ESMTP, which is specified in [RFC 2920](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2920#section-3.1), says:

> The EHLO, DATA, VRFY, EXPN, TURN, QUIT, and NOOP commands can only appear as the last command in a group since their success or failure produces a change of state which the client SMTP must accommodate.

This means that you can remove the `sleep` commands after `mail from` and `rcpt to`, but you should introduce a `sleep` after `echo "data"` before continuing with the message which is to be delivered. (Just to be clear: You need to wait for the server's response; `sleep` is just a hack to achieve that.)